# Blinking white stripes in IE10 only (bug in IE10?)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fadein, fadeout, visual-glitch

Since IE10 is around, some clients of me complain about a nasty glitch (shows blinking white stripes) in some projects of mine. This problem occur when a part of the screen is fading in or out. I think it has something to do with opacity. This is a IE10 problem only, because other browsers does not have any problems with the code, including earlier versions of IE.

The weird thing is that it is not always there, sometimes there is no problem but overall it is very annoying.
To give you some example, go to the following site (with use of IE10):
http://www.meezingeninrotterdam.nl (it is a dutch site)

Next: click for example on the search-icon on the page, you can find it on the right on the menu bar. You will notice the glitch (maybe also in the slideshow), if not, try again by closing the dialog and open it again.

I think this is a bug in IE10 but when I am able to fix this with a little change to the code, i will try it.

For your information:

- Using jQuery 1.5.1
- The site is heavily based on Ajax, for example for the slide shows and dialogs
- I don't use any third party code (or plugins) except jQuery
- The site is cross-browser compatible and don't use hacks and is W3C valid (except the CSS, that's is not possible with all kind of browsers).
- All code is compiled (Google enclosure compiler) or minified (YUI compressor) for distribution

What I don't want to do:

- Drastic changes in the structure of the website
- No extra CSS file for IE10 only
- Update to a newer version of jQuery because of some incompatibility issues.

What i have tried:

- Upgrade jQuery but has incompatibility issues with existing code
- Using the orginal code (not minified) but has the same issues described above
- Analyzing the code but did not find an reason that might be a problem

Does have somebody a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of time, I got the answer to the problem (but is not a real answer).
Still believing that it is a bug in IE, it has something to do with the used hardware. I have two cards in my laptop, integrated graphics and a more powerful NVIDIA graphic card.

IE is using the more powerful hardware at default (the NVIDIA card) 3D settings and at this point something go wrong. When I use the NVIDIA configuration console to force that IE must use the integrated graphics instead of the NVIDIA graphic card the flicker issue is gone.

This is not a solution to my clients, because most of them has just one graphic card in their system and cannot do anything about it.

It proves that there is nothing wrong with my code, it is a problem of IE in combination with the used graphic card (DirectX 3D settings) in the system.

**EDIT:**
See also:

- http://steamcommunity.com/app/20500/discussions/0/810921273846416279/
- http://www.bit-tech.net/news/bits/2013/03/04/ie10-bug-hybrid-graphics/1